# CSS/Blueprint Overwrite to default select field

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I am using blueprint as my CSS framework. I am not happy with the way it customizes select field, and want to go back to default.

Here the CSS generated by Blueprint:

```
select {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Do you think there is a way to achieve this? (My issue to get back border-style default.. I cannot use none, or inherit..)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each browser renders the select element differently. Furthermore the rendering of the select element is effected by the operating system. You might have to simply delete the above CSS.

Comment: I didn't want to hack blueprint default files.. It's for this I would prefer overwrite it. I think I don't have the choice here..

Comment: In that case, you have to manually check what values the browser applies as user agent styles for the above mentioned properties. For example FF 4.0.1 applies as "select { background-color: -moz-combobox; border-style: inset; border-width: 2px; }". You will have to check the same way for each and every browser that you want to target.